# Rails Array Conditions Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've written the following method to combine the `References` of `Sections` model and it's children:

```
def combined_references
    ids = []
    ids << self.id
    self.children.each do |child|
      ids << child.id
    end
    Reference.where("section_id = ?", ids)
  end
```

But `section.combined_references` returns the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT `references`.* FROM `references`  WHERE (section_id = 3,4)
```

It seems to have collected the correct values for ids, have I structured the query incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transform last line to:

```
Reference.where(section_id: ids)
```

and it should produce:

```
SELECT `references`.* FROM `references`  WHERE section_id IN (3,4)
```

And you can shorten your code by one line with :

```
 ids = []
 ids << self.id
```

to

```
 ids = [self.id]
```

Answer (score 2):

it's invalid statement
    WHERE (section_id = 3,4)
correct would be

```
WHERE (section_id in (3,4))
```

Please use:

```
Reference.where(:section_id => ids)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this instead:

```
def combined_references
  ids = self.children.map(&:id).push(self.id)
  Reference.where(section_id: ids)
end
```

You can also query the database with:

```
Reference.where("section_id in (?)", ids)
```

The following has the most readability in my opinion:

```
def combined_references
  Reference.where(section_id: self_and_children_ids)
end

private

def self_and_children_ids
  self.children.map(&:id).push(self.id)
end
```